# Edit Posts Page but not category specific pages?

Tags: posts, categories, blog

Is there a way to edit the page that shows all your posts? But not affect the specific categorized pages? I have been trying, and cannot seem to find a solution.

Comment: Depending on how your site is configured, index.php is likely driving your list of posts, the blog 'home'.  Your theme likely contains a category.php template as well which renders the category pages.

Comment: Yes there is. Hard for anyone to say without seeing your site/code but have a look at https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Page template in which display all posts with your custom markup.

```
<?php

/**
 * Template Name: My Custom Blog
 *
 */

// The Query
$args = array('posts_per_page'=>-1);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Name this page as: "page-custom_blog.php"
After, just publish a new page assigning this template.

[image: Assigning a page template]

Hope it helps.

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/